# UINavigationController: Apply Common Padding/Margin to all Popped View Controller's Views

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` and I would like the view of every view controller that is popped onto the stack to have a common padding/margin (e.g. 25 pixels on all sides). What is the best way to accomplish this?

I originally thought that I could implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and inside the `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated` or `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated` methods, simply change the frame of the view controller that was about to be displayed. This does not seem to have an effect though.

I tried to do the same thing inside the view controller's `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` methods, but this also did not work. Ideally, I don't want to put any logic in the controllers anyway, as they may not always be used inside a navigation controller.

One last idea that I haven't tried yet is to create a "wrapper" `UIViewController` that would actually get pushed onto this stack. This wrapper would add the real view controller's view as a subview with a frame that would provide the desired margin. The downside here is that I would need to subclass `UINavigationController` and override `pushViewController:animated`, where the wrapper would be initialized and pushed. Apple's documentation indicates that `UINavigationController` is not meant to be subclassed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried to implement the "last idea" mentioned above, but hit a snag. Since the view controller being displayed is actually "wrapped" by another view controller, and the wrapper is actually pushed on the stack, the `navigationController` property on the view controller being displayed is `nil`. This means I can't get a handle to the navigation controller in order to push another view controller on top.

Comment: Another data point: changing the view controller's view's frame in `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated` actually does work, but the view controller first appears in the original frame and then is resized after the fact, which looks bad. Changing the frame in `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated` has no effect though.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by putting a "wrapper" `UIView` around the `UIViewController`'s `view` instead of the `UIViewController` itself. The wrapper view then pads the subview by setting the subview's frame in the `layoutSubviews` method.

I've attached the code I used for convenience. To use, replace your `UINavigationController` with the `PaddedNavigationController`, and set the `PaddedNavigationController`'s `insets` property.

`PaddedNavigationController.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PaddedNavigationController : UINavigationController
{
    UIEdgeInsets _insets;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets insets;

@end
```

`PaddedNavigationController.m`:

```
#import "PaddedNavigationController.h"

@interface PaddedView : UIView
{
    UIView *_view;
    UIEdgeInsets _insets;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets insets;

+ (PaddedView *) wrapView:(UIView *)view withInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets;
- (id) initWithView:(UIView *)view insets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets;

@end


@implementation PaddedNavigationController

@synthesize insets = _insets;

- (void) pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    //check if the UIViewController's view has already been wrapped by the PaddedView; don't want to wrap it twice
    if(![viewController.view isKindOfClass:[PaddedView class]])
    {
        viewController.view = [PaddedView wrapView:viewController.view withInsets:self.insets];
    }
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}

- (void) setInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets
{
    _insets = insets;

    //loop through this navigation controller's view controllers and set the new insets on any PaddedViews
    for(UIViewController *viewController in self.viewControllers)
    {
        if([viewController.view isKindOfClass:[PaddedView class]])
        {
            PaddedView *padded = (PaddedView *)viewController.view;
            padded.insets = insets;
        }
    }
}

@end


@implementation PaddedView

@synthesize insets = _insets;

+ (PaddedView *) wrapView:(UIView *)view withInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets
{
    return [[[PaddedView alloc] initWithView:view insets:insets] autorelease];
}

- (id) initWithView:(UIView *)view insets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets
{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:view.frame])
    {
        _insets = insets;
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        _view = [view retain];
        [self addSubview:view];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [_view release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    //apply the insets to the subview
    _view.frame = CGRectMake(self.insets.left, self.insets.top, self.frame.size.width - self.insets.left - self.insets.right, self.frame.size.height - self.insets.top - self.insets.bottom);
}

- (void) setInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)insets
{
    _insets = insets;
    //we need to re-layout the subviews as the insets have changed
    [self layoutSubviews];
}

@end
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this out, but I'm accepting it as it looks like a pretty good solution (at least better than anything I could come up with). Thanks!

Comment: After going down this road, it turns out that this doesn't actually work so well. Your view controllers really can't be agnostic to the fact that their views are wrapped. Trying to add subviews and using the view controller's view's bounds to determine the subview's bounds will result in undesired outcome.

Comment: Additionally, this approach is problematic when memory warnings occur and the view controllers' views are reloaded, without being wrapped in a `PaddedView` instance.